# Extract best linear regression model between multiple columns in R

Tags: r, regression

This might take a little to explain but here goes.

For the sake of this example lets say I have 2 columns that relate to real world observed data (RealX) and 4 columns that relate to predictions (ModX) from a model output of that real world data. To complicate things the data is grouped by a categorical variable.

What I want to do is determine the best linear regression model (lm(RealX ~ ModX)) between the observed and predicted values for each categorical variable. I'm not really too fussed about which columns give the best model just the R squared and P value of the best model for each category.

Here's some sample data to illustrate the data structure:

```
RealA <- c(3,2,2,6,7,9,3,1,4,6)
RealB <- c(3,2,1,5,8,8,4,2,5,5)
Mod1 <- c(2,2,3,4,6,7,4,1,5,6)
Mod2 <- c(1,4,2,4,7,8,4,2,6,5)
Mod3 <- c(3,2,2,5,8,7,5,3,4,5)
Mod4 <- c(3,1,1,3,8,7,3,2,5,6)
Cat <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
DF <- data.frame(Cat, RealA, RealB, Mod1, Mod2, Mod3, Mod4)
```

So for the above example I'd like to find the R squared and p values of the best linear regression model for categories A and B.

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for the best *Simple* linear regression, where you only have one predictor variable (outside of the intercept)?

Comment: Yes the best simple linear regression i.e. lm(RealX ~ ModX)

Comment: Use `step` for finding it.